# Find all dictionary keys with duplicate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary where some of the values are duplicates.
I want to print the Key: Value of each duplicate.
So, with the below dictionary:

```
animal = {"cat" : "23", "dog" : "21", "lion" : "23"}
```

I want to print:

```
cat: 23
lion: 23
```

I have this code below, but that only prints the later:

```
animal = {"cat" : "23", "dog" : "21", "lion" : "23"}
duplicates = []
unique = []
for x in animal:
    if animal[x] not in unique:
        unique.append(animal[x])
    else:
        duplicates.append(x + animal[x])

print(duplicates)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest re-thinking your solution. You can invert your dictionary by mapping values to lists of keys.

```
dupe = {}
for k, v in animal.items():
    dupe.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Next, filter your dictionary to retain only those keys with multiple values.

```
dupe = {k : dupe[k] for k in dupe if len(dupe[k]) > 1}
print(dupe)
# {'23': ['cat', 'lion']}
```

This solution will find all duplicate values from the original along with their keys.